# hash table load factor a and n slots, open adressing for collisions

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashtable, probability, hashcode

I was at the high freq Trading interview they asked me all mathematical side of data structures one question was:
load factor a=1-1/(sqrt(n)logn), what is the time for unsuccessful search? state the answer using only 'n'

Comment: the question is incomprehensible without a clear elaboration

Answer (score 1):

The term `1-1/(sqrt(n)*log(n))` approaches 1.0 as `n` increases. When `n==10`, the value is 0.9048. When `n==1000000`, the value is 0.9999. (I'm using log base 2.)

With a full hash table (which is what a load factor of 1.0 means) and open addressing, you'd have to examine every item. So the time for an unsuccessful search would be O(n).

Comment: So simple and so well explained. Thx.